# Any idea what this plant is?

Tags: identification

Anyone have idea what does this plant called? Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

It looks a lot like some kind of [celosia (Amaranth family)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Celosia).

See this picture from Burpee Seed Co. of [red celosia](http://www.burpee.com/flowers/celosia/celosia-fresh-look-red-prod000152.html),

[image: red celosia]

and this one of [celosia argentea](http://www.public.asu.edu/~camartin/plants/Plant%20html%20files/Celosia1.jpg).

[image: Celosia argentea]

Comment: I think you're right about the family. According to [WELLGROW Horti Trading](http://www.wellgrowhorti.com/Page/Commercial/Flower%20Seeds/Celosia%20Plumosa.htm), Celosia Plumosa is "one of the most popular landscape plants used in Malaysia."  See that page for information and more pictures.

Comment: ...and it is a great food plant.  Amaranth is a very underused underplanted plant.